# Behavior Flow from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I use a Google Analytics in my android application, a few days before today I receive an email that means *In Oct. 2019 Google will sunset Google Analytics for mobile apps reporting and the Google Analytics Services SDK.*

So I decided to migrate to Firebase Analytics.
I am a little bit disgusted because Firebase Analytics doesn't have a feature called 'Behaviour Flow'.

I want to track user behaviour / flow, how can I achieve this with Firebase Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do exactly the same thing as you did in GA. There is no "behavior flow" that you can turn on or track. Even the "screen views" have turned into just event based.

I think the closest thing out of the box would be using funnels, identifying the funnels that you care about and track those.

Alternatively, you can connect the firebase data to bigquery, export and analyse the data that way, but you probably would need to do a lot of processing.

Comment: I can't understand why Google pushed us to an way inferior product

Comment: Firebase isn't an "inferior" product, just a different one. They sunsetted the GA SDK because they introduced a new data streams (still in beta right now) allowing you make Firebase data show up on the GA dashboard.
With it you can create a cross-platform report using GA + Firebase data, and I think you can create funnel views, but I haven't tried it myself.
More info : https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new-way-unify-app-and-website-measurement-google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics is event-based so they don't support the features that exist in Google Analytics. However; it lets you ingest the raw data into your BigQuery project for free unlike Google Analytics so you can do path analysis either with SQL or use a tool that works on top of Firebase export such as [Rakam](https://rakam.io/solution/firebase).